# Waht Date of 2011-01-01T15:03:01.012345Z format in php

Tags: php, date-format

I want to know what format of 2011-01-01T15:03:01.012345Z
how I can check the format in php?

Comment: you need to work a little on your question quality

Comment: this is a generic ISO date format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kinda `ISO 8601`, likely produced by a `date.toISOString()` in JavaScript.

As in PHP, you can output or parse it via `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z'`

For example: 

`echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');    // => 2017-03-20T14:12:58.000000Z`